# Google App Engine "The error was: Fetch to /_ah/remote_api/ failed with status 404."

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Friends,

```
    I am working new to Google App Engine. I have learnt by myself. I am struck with a issue. I am trying to Copy entities from one app to another. I select all the entities and click on copy to app button in the bottom.
```

I gave my Target Application’s Remote API URL: and clicked "Copy Entities". It gives me error like ""Copy Job Status
There was a problem kicking off the jobs. The error was:
Fetch to http://xyzxyzxyz.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api/ failed with status 404.

I tried to edit app.yaml and added this piece of code to (Python)
    builtins:
    - remote_api: on.

Where am i doing mistake. I want to copy entities from one app to another. Your help is valuable for my further process in my work.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you enabled remote_api in builtins section of  app.yaml ?

Comment: yes i have enabled. I am not sure where this app.yaml file is located correctly. May be i have made changes in a wrong file. Can u please guide me where i can find app.yaml file..

Comment: It will be in the root of your project directory and it's directives will be deployed when you use appcfg.  YOu couldn't deploy a new version of your app if app.yaml was not found when running appcfg.

Comment: Its of No use. I have added buildin's in app.yaml. Tim Hoffman. What your are saying is right. But i am not able to copy files from one application server to another Application server. It always gives me same error "There was a problem kicking off the jobs. The error was:
Fetch to http://xxxyyyzzz.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api failed with status 404. Please tell me how can i find that appengine.py file. I think i need to add my appID there. I cannot find that path.

Comment: Yes I have found it. I have made the changes u asked me to do. I ll keep updated once everything works fine...

Comment: Can someone tell me how to Upload the modified version of your application using appcfg.py update. Cmd prompt i gave the correct path and gave appcfg.py update.. Its not getting updated... Please help me..